# Unable to access CiviCRM permissions under Joomla Global Configuration

Tags: joomla, permissions

This is a new install of Joomla! 3.10.2 Stable [ Daraja ] with CiviCRM version 5.37.0 installed.

I am trying to access CiviCRM permissions from the Joomla menu bar: System/Global Configuration/CiviCRM

I am receiving the following error:

"Too few arguments to function CRM_Core_Permission_Base::getAllModulePermissions(), 1 passed in /home/mysite/www/www/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/joomla/libraries/joomla/form/fields/civiperms.php on line 282 and exactly 2 expected"

I am logging in to Joomla with administrator privileges.
I can only access CiviCrm as administrator.

Contacts, Members and Contribution data was imported from a previous CiviCRM installation from another server that was also running Joomla.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Keith

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: Joomla! 3.10.2 Stable [ Daraja ] My hosting provider thinks its a bug.

Comment: Sorry, I have CiviCRM version 5.37.0 installed.

Comment: Thank you! Your question fixed the problem. This version of CiviCRM was installed by the hosting provider due to a previous issue. Updating to 5.41.1 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed with an update.